# Machine independent C library for printing the binary representation of data types to stdout

Tags: c

I'm curious as to peoples thoughts on this small library I have made. I noticed there are no functions in the C standard library to accomplish this task.

I have tried to make the code machine independent. If anyone has access to machines where short != 2 byte, int != 4 byte, long != 8 byte or where bytes themselves are not 8 bits. I would be curious as to the test results.

[GitHub](https://github.com/zer0ptr/libprintb)

The current functions for printing the binary representations are all slight modifications of the below:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void printcb(char n)
{
    int i;
    int type_bits = CHAR_BIT;
    int mask = 1 << type_bits - 1;

    for (i = 0; i < type_bits; ++i) {
        if (n & mask)
            putc('1', stdout);
        else
            putc('0', stdout);
        n <<= 1;
    }
    putc('\n', stdout);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The left shift operator on signed types is tricky and will easily lead you to undefined behavior.

To put it formally, here is a quote from §6.5.7/4 *Bitwise shift operators* of a C11 draft, emphasis added:

> The result of `E1 << E2` is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup> , reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. **If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is
>   the resulting value; *otherwise, the behavior is undefined*.**

`char` is signed on a lot of platforms (likely including on the one you're testing). Therefore the following expression can fall foul of the "non-negative" constraint in the standardese above:

```
n <<= 1;
```

If `n` is negative, the expression has undefined behavior, even on common platforms with boring 8-bit (signed) chars.

---

There's a problem with the following too, on stranger implementations, related to the second constraint:

```
int mask = 1 << type_bits - 1;
```

On a platform where `sizeof(int) == sizeof(char)` (possible with e.g. `CHAR_BITS==16` implementations, see [What platforms have something other than 8-bit char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098149/what-platforms-have-something-other-than-8-bit-char) for examples), that shift will push the `1` into the sign bit, which has undefined behavior: 1 x 2<sup>CHAR_BITS-1</sup> is not  representable (at least in 2's complement, 1's complement or sign/magnitude representations – they stop at 2<sup>CHAR_BITS-1</sup>-1. No idea if there are other representations that fulfill the C standard's conditions and would be able to represent that).

---

**TLDR:** unsigned types are the bit-twiddler's friend.

Answer (score 4):

- You can just call [`putchar()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/putchar), which automatically prints to `stdout`:

  ```
  putchar('1');
  ```
- The conditionals can instead be a ternary statement within `putchar()`:

  ```
  putchar(n & mask ? '1' : '0');
  ```

`putchar` is often better suited for single-character output. `putchar` only has to pass a character directly to the output. This particular code isn't exactly performance-critical but it's useful to acquire good coding habits from the beginning.